# How to test facebook pixel dynamic button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-pixel

I have my shopping cart setup to fire the facebook Addtocart pixel tracking only when the add to cart button is pressed.

So naturally the facebook pixel helper shows an error that the pixel did not load.

What I am wondering if there is anyway to test it, besides waiting to see if it is working in the facebook pixel dashboard.

This is my code on the product information page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="40" /><span class="tdbLink"><button id="tdb1" type="submit" id="addToCartButton">Add to Cart</button></span>



                <script type="text/javascript">
            $( '#addToCartButton' ).click(function() {
                fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
                    content_ids: ['40'],
                    content_type: 'product'

                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the network tab of your Chrome Dev Tools panel,

Whenever an event is detected, FB makes a network call to send the details to its server.

Use the network tab filter with keyword "facebook" or "fb" to see all the outgoing network connections to Facebook from your website.